# Simple on-press event Javascript

Tags: javascript

I currently have a div element. Is there a way in Javascript that when we press the Ctrl key, the div shows up, and when we release (unpress) the key, the div disappear? Thank you! (something like onClick...) (Ctrl key code is 17)

Comment: No! This is not a duplicated question! The link you gave me can't solve it! Please release this question to normal

Comment: Maybe you could bind the keydown event on the window with `$(window).bind('keydown', function(event) { if (event.keyCode == KEY_CODE_OF_CTRL_KEY) { $(div).show(); }});`. To disapear on keyup you have to do the same just vice versa.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I found out about onkeydown and onkeyup :)

Comment: You're welcome. This sounds great. If my comment was helpful, then vote it up please.

Comment: Dome it. Have a good day